# Can't install or try Live Cds's of Ubuntu and Kubuntu

Tags: installation, live-cd

I see the following messages from both primary and alternate Ubuntu and Kubuntu Live Cds.

```
error: "prefix" is not set.
```

then,

```
booting a command list
you need to load a kernel first
```

Both these messages are displayed very early in the boot process, the first just after the boot begins and the second immediately after I select from the "Try or install" menu.

Selecting any option from "Try or install" leaves the system locked that needs a hard reboot.

I always see this on Live Cd's of Ubuntu/Kubuntu 12.04. But never on a Live USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say 'burnt onto a CD'.  It should be on a DVD as it is oversized.  Brasero would tell you that.  If you used a buggy CD burner it might have burned you a buggy CD.  This is why you are not getting the problem with a USB stick.

Comment: I should have noticed that.  However, I have to say that the ISO images are showing as just under 700 MB on the mirrors and while they are downloading, but they're coming in at 730+ MB on my drive.

Comment: @jonc This sounds like the classic albeit ever annoying [*MiB versus MB*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte#History) confusion. 700 MiB is essentially 734 MB. For a related commentary on this from someone associated with [se], there is this: [Gigabyte: Decimal vs. Binary](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/gigabyte-decimal-vs-binary.html)