# Can't install Ubuntu since 10.10

Tags: installation, bumblebee

When I try to install ubuntu on my notebook from a disk, I get the screen that asks be what I want to do, (boot live, install etc)... no matter what I do, when I get to the point where I select an option, the disc will start to load, I will see the little man a circle with the keyboard under him, and then shortly after I get this screen:

[image]

I have been having this problem since version 10.10. 10.04 worked, and ever since the 10.10, i've tried the new versions and they all give me the same error.

I really love Ubuntu, and I want to use it as my main OS, but this issue prevents me from using it as something other than a virtual machine (which works).

I've tried the following things to resolve this problem.

- Tried 32bit and 64 bit OS'
- Tried multiple download ISO's
- Tried multiple installation versions
- Tried upgrading from version 10.04

With this, I get an error on the upgrade, my upgrade process freezes, and no key combination will undo the freeze.

- I have updated my BIOS to the newest version.
- Run hardware diagnostics on my machine.
- Looked for BIOS options to specify Video card / CPU video allocation (There's no options for anything like this on my BIOS)
- I have tried installing Fedora 15-16, and I get the same problem.
- Googled the world for a solution, and come up empty.

Here are the important specs of my notebook

- ASUS G51Jx
- Intel® Core™ i7 720QM
- 4gb DDR3 RAM
- NVIDIA® GeForce® GTS 360M 1GB GDDR5 VRAM
- More [here if you need](http://ca.asus.com/en/Notebooks/Gaming_Powerhouse/G51Jx/#specifications)

Thanks to anyone who can help. I really want to get using Ubuntu as my main OS again.

Comment: Have you updated the Nvidia drivers??

Comment: I can't update video drivers without having an OS installed first, and that's the main problem. I've updated the firmware on my BIOS, but that didn't fix it either :(

Comment: ASUS users see this http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/995187/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you boot from the live CD press and hold down the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. This will, after having selected the language, enter the Grub menu:

[image]

Press <kbd>F6</kbd> at his screen and select *"nomodeset"* as a boot option to prevent loading of video drivers during boot.

If that does not resolve the issue try with the [alternate CD](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.isohttp://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso) for a text based installation.

In case you will not be able to boot into a graphical desktop you may try to install the Nvidia graphic drivers from a terminal, e.g. with [jockey-text](https://askubuntu.com/a/11464/3940).

Additional note from comment: after a successful installation we may be able to boot to *"Recovery Mode"* (again hold left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key for Grub menu) to install graphic drivers, or if that fails drop to a shell to proceed driver installation from command line.

Comment: I think I'm on the right track with this solution. I was able to install the OS using nomodeset. However, when I boot up the OS I have a blank screen. Like you said, I may have to install the new NVidia drivers using terminal. This will test my novice Linux Skills :P Thank you for the solution! This seems to have been the right way to get around my issue. :)

Comment: Yup!!! I ran the OS in safe graphics mode, and then I was able to get past the black screen. I then updated the drivers, and restarted and am good to go! Thank you so much :D you have no idea how long this has stressed me out!

Comment: @Frantumn: Really glad you got it sorted out. Just for the records: how did you install which drivers? Did you use jockey-text or did you install the driver with apt-get?

Comment: When I was in grub, I selected the kernel boot that was recovery mode. Then I chose to boot once with failsafe graphics mode. That allowed me to boot into my desktop environment. Once in there, I simply went to the hardware drivers utility in settings, and installed the newest NVidia driver. I restarted and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You say a CD.. 12.04 will not fit on a CD.  Where and how did you make your install disk?  If it is a downloaded iso try burning it to a DVD.  The Windows CD burner is known to be buggy.

Comment: ??? 12.04 does fit on a CD.  Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: Apologies, it was burned to DVD and CD (I'm sure I've tried both over the time I've had this issue). But even still, I've tried numerous ISO images, and discs, I don't think it has to do with the burning software, or the disc. I've used Power ISO primarily, not the windows burning software.I've changed my post to say Disk.

Comment: I'm puzzled.  The little man in a circle usually only appears before any options are entered.  This seems a bit different as you select an option and then see the little man.  I wonder what is happening here.

Comment: Writing this from memory, I'm sorry for confusing the steps.
To better describe, I'll use this link... I get the screen between steps 2 and 3. I never see Step 3
http://screamable.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-complete-step-by-step-guide.html

Comment: fossfreedom - I've seen quite a lot of problems on Ubuntu Answers in which folk had burned a CD using Windows and it would not work properly.  If they burn to a DVD it often works.  I have not tried it myself - I took the testing daily build which had to go on a DVD.  The size of the iso is marked as 701 MB - maybe it's the Windows burner that gives the problem.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/131701/cant-install-or-try-live-cdss-of-ubuntu-and-kubuntu/131712#comment158784_131712

Comment: @Frantumn For possible future reference you can verify your install media is good by running a test which is included with it. When you boot from your install media, pressing any key while you see the [**"man in the circle" image**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tSYiR.png) will bring up the menu screen shown in [**Takat's answer**](http://askubuntu.com/a/134081/52923) to this question. Select and run the middle menu entry, `Check disc for defects`, to verify your install media has no defects.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press **any key** before the Ubuntu installation welcome screen (to open the ["Ubuntu CD Advanced Welcome Page Options"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions?action=show&redirect=BootParameters#Ubuntu_CD_Advanced_Welcome_Page_Options).
2. Press **F6** and select the **nomodeset** option and finish the installation.
3. Hold the **shift** key while booting from the new installation (to access the GRUB options) and select the [**recovery mode**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode#Booting_into_recovery_mode) in the GRUB options.
4. Using the recovery mode, enable Internet access and open the root console to execute this commands:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install nvidia-current 
    exit
```