# 12.04 installation leaves me with a blank screen, changing boot options doesn't help

Tags: installation, wubi, screen, nomodeset

The problem of seeing simply a blinker seems to be occurring quite frequently online, but I have not found any solution that has helped.

I am trying to install from wubi, and previously I've had to uninstall and reinstall ubuntu many times to try to get it to work; I also have had a working copy of 11.10 on my machine (Asus U46E) before, but had to uninstall it after my computer froze during an upgrade to 12.04, and was rendered useless despite what solutions online tried to tell me.

At this point, I almost had 11.04 working because I was able to edit the boot option to xforcevesa and remote quiet splash during startup, but attempting to update-grub [this time I mistakenly updated to quick splash xforcevesa instead of removing quick splash] gave me an "alloc Magic broken at 0xsomething". Newer versions don't get me much further.  With the boot options set to "quiet splash ", I have the same problem.  Removing quiet splash and going with one of the many other options out there simply gets me to the Booting Node activating processors, or something to that effect, and stops moving there.

Is there any other solution out there?  And why would it not work now when it did the first time?

Answer (score 1):

Check all the comments on this thread. I am the person who posted the question. If any of this seems familiar, then I'll do my best to help walk you through any steps.
My main guess to focus on would be the step where you boot into recovery mode with grub, then select safe graphical boot. But check it all, just in case.

[Can't install Ubuntu since 10.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134029/cant-install-ubuntu-since-10-10)

This boot repair may help too
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Nope.  Mine simply gives me a black screen with a blinking cursor, and I don't even get to the point where I can pick recovery mode

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like GRUB may need to be fixed then. I don't know a lot about it, but my assumption would be, use a live boot disc to somehow re-install GRUB.
Check out this option and try it out.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I ended up having to ask a person I've never met to make a Windows 7 Recovery disk for me.

Anyway, I was unable to get Boot-Repair to work.  Regular bootup on it has the same problem as Ubuntu, and Failsafe didn't connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I think this is what happened.

When we installed 12.04, it actually placed the bootloader on the flash drive that I installed it from. So when I booted from the flash after installing, it would actually boot from my real hard disk and it would work.

I had to install grub and update it to the hard disk and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Go to BIOS > Security> I / O interface Security> "New card Interface".  Set it to Locked.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1662577&page=3