# Unable to install Ubuntu on my computer. Black and white static appear

Tags: 12.04, installation, nvidia, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't install Ubuntu since 10.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134029/cant-install-ubuntu-since-10-10)

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer for some time now. It works on my laptop, but won't install on my desktop. I've also tried installing 11.04, and the same problem occurs. The purple screen comes up, the orange dots load, then the screen turn into to a black and white checkerboard, and nothing else happens. I believe the issue has to do with my nvidia graphics card, as I have heard it can cause issues for Ubuntu. I am booting from a USB drive. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is not compatible with all computers, mainly due to the fact that computers are expected to run with Windows (unless Mac, of course).

I'm not saying that this is the problem or that your graphics card is not the problem, but perhaps you should check the list and see if your computer is [here](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportMachinesDesktops) and [here](http://friendly.ubuntu.com)

The first link may not have been updated in a while, but was the original program of the second link. I haven't used either of them before, but I assume the first one has a bigger list than the second due to the fact that the first is older, but I'm not sure how old either one is. I used a different link before downloading Ubuntu but can't find it now. I recommend checking both sites.