# Newbie. Cannot upgrade to 12.04

Tags: installation, boot, upgrade

I am trying to use Ubuntu over Windows XP on my home computer but have completely fubared it.

I first loaded an old disc I had of version 8.xxx.  It loaded fine and seemed to be running well.  I ran the update function and tried to update the computer to version 10.xxx.  With about 15 minutes left in the upgrade process terminal said something was wrong and was exiting, but it never did.

I turned the computer off.  Upon re-boot it tries to load grub with a countdown.  If I hit escape before it tries to load grub it takes me to a menu to try different versions of 10.04.  One of the recovery modes seemed to do something like creating a maintenance shell and it gives me a root command line and tells me control d will terminate the shell.  Is there a command I can type on this line?  Other than that the computer will not load anything.  it comes up with an error stqating a kernal panic etc etc etc.  I have tried all of the options on the 10.04 options screen all with the same result.
I made a live cd of 12.04.2 and tried to install it by re-starting the computer with the disc in the drive.

Ubuntu seems to load because I can see part of the tool bar across the top of the screen and see where the program is asking me if I want to use or intall Ubunty, but I only have about 3/4 of my screen and the part that I can see is filled with horizontal lines.  I can see the cursor moving because it changes the line pattern on the screen.  The screen also seems to be divided vertically into about 4 or 5 segments.  I can click on some of the items in the toolbar across the top of the screen, but cannot read the menus or the window that the clicks open.  Is this a graphics card problem?

Here are my thoughts.  Go back and re-load the version 8.xxx and get it running and then see if I can upgrade to the version 12.04 using the live cd from a function computer.  Can I jump versions or do I need to make my way up the upgrade chain?  If I have to go up the chain can I download the in between versions and burn them to a disc?
Anyone else have any ideas to get me back up and running?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Andy Yes, formatting is a little different here. See [formatting help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2):

> Can I jump versions or do I need to make my way up the upgrade chain?

You can only jump from LTS to LTS.

> If I have to go up the chain can I download the in between versions and burn them to a disc?

Yes. But I would bot bother...

My advice would be...

1. use a live cd to boot and mount your systems partitions.
2. backup all your private files OR put all your private data to a data partition if you have one.
3. Format system (but not the partition you saved your private data).
4. Install 12.04 or 12.10. During the part where your can partition if you put private data on to a partition, only add the partition and create a mount point (make sure you do not format it).

---

Also: always check if you can copy files from a backup back to your system before you start deleting files.

Comment: So if I can get my system back to running normally on version 8.xxx, not sure if it is an lts version or not, probably is because I tend to lean toward the safer options, I, in theory, could then re-boot with the 12.04 live cd and upgrade that way?

Comment: Is there a huge advantage to running version 12.04 over version 8?

Comment: Just so I am clear, you would advise upgrading from my version 8 to 10, then 11 and then 12 using live cd's each time?  I appreciate your patience.

Comment: It does not look like version 11 has an lts version.  Should I skip version 11 in my upgrade chain?

Comment: No. I would advice to burn 12.04 or 12.10 to a disc (on your system or someone elses), back up your files and clean install 12.04/10. No installing of any other old Ubuntu.

Comment: OK. I have a live cd of 12.04 lts but when trying to install I get the problems listed above.  3/4 screen, crazy lines all over the screen etc.   Graphic card problem?  I read something about pressing shift + f6 on the purple boot screen.  Would this help?

Comment: This: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134029/cant-install-ubuntu-since-10-10?